# One-hot encoding

Tags: regression

I am going through tensor-flow tutorial and noticed that they use one-hot encoding in regression [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py). I don't fully understand how it works. Let us take oversimplified case of ordinary least square regression. Assume we have y = [1,2,3] and x = [cat, dog, mouse]. Converting to one hot vector we get

```
cat = [0,0,1]
dog = [0,1,0]
mouse = [1,0,0]
```

how does regression equation looks now? Is it multivariate regression now?

```
y = alpha + beta*x_1 + beta*x_2 + beta*x_3,
```

where x_1, x_2, x_3 are coordinates of one-hot vector?

P.S. I am interested more in mechanics of this set up, not so much meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you turn it into three different variables, however this is not called multivariate regression, that indicates multiple output variables, not inputs. (Thanks to Simon for correcting me)

Comment: Multivariate regression typically refers to a regression model with more than 1 outcome, which is not true in this case

Comment: Oops you are correct, I will change my answer.

Comment: @Simon, thank you for the comment, could you give any references to your statement?

Comment: In most statistics textbooks you'll find that multiple regression is more than 1 predictor, while more than 1 outcome is multivariate regression/analysis. For example, you can see on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_statistics

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is the standard approach to convert categorical variables for fitting a model. In this case it would be used to train a neural network.
So each category of a categorical variable is represented as a separate vector.

Note that you do not need to do this for binary variables such as Male/Female as the presence of one category implies absence of the other category, so instead of using a variable such as `Gender = Male/Female`; you could convert it into a variable called `is_female = 0/1`.

If this dataset is used to fit a regression model, the proper nomenclature should be multiple linear regression.